# data-main attribute on <script> tag that doesn't load require.js works

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I did somewhat an accident discovery that I was able to load my data-main js file in a file that doesn't load requireJS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="requirejs.config.js" data-main="theme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="requirejs.js"></script>
```

and it perfectly loads my theme.js file

is this an intentional feature of requirejs? or a bug?

I hope this isn't a bug.

the contents of my requirejs.config.js are below

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: '/js/',
    paths: {
        'jquery': "lib/jquery/jquery",
        'bootstrap': "lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap"
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': ['jquery']
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery': 'jQueryNoConflict'
        },
        'jQueryNoConflict': {
            'jquery': 'jquery'
        }
    }
}
```

I check every samples here and seems they are not doing what I accidentally discovered.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main

Comment: From those docs - "You will typically use a data-main script to set configuration options and then load the first application module." And you're not doing that, you have a separate call for the config file and put the first application module in the `data-main`. I can only assume that you're getting lucky in that it's loading the scripts in the correct order by chance, it's certainly not guaranteed with that setup.

Comment: My best guess is this: RequireJS needs to use special tricks to actually "find" the script node that it was executed from. It's likely it made a mistake and assumed the first one was its origin, and then used data attributes from that one. I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the behavior your report with RequireJS 2.1.20. You can see [here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/659fdf2d379d4f2fadc98c4ff147d3755030cdd6/require.js#L1967) the code that performs the check:

```
if (isBrowser && !cfg.skipDataMain) {
    //Figure out baseUrl. Get it from the script tag with require.js in it.
    eachReverse(scripts(), function (script) {
```

The `eachReverse` loop looks at all `script` elements in reverse order. Due to the way the DOM works, only the `script` element that loads RequireJS and those elements *before* it in the HTML will be looped over because the HTML is still in the process of being parsed by the browser when this code executes. (Consequently, the DOM nodes for the `script` elements after the one that loads RequireJS do not exist yet.) The function in the loop searches until it runs into a `script` element that has `data-main`. It could be the one that loaded RequireJS, or it could be any before it.

I don't know whether to consider this a bug or a feature with an unexpected side-effect. One might want to change the logic to check that the `src` attribute of the `script` element *also* points to a file containing RequireJS. However, it seems to me this would be brittle. (It cannot be just a naive file name comparison because if you decide to change the file name, the code will break.)

Comment: "It cannot be just a naive file name comparison because if you decide to change the file name, the code will break." well I was thinking the same reason. I was debugging same line of code and I found this

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1182 what can you say about that?

Answer (score 0):

Your data-main is on the wrong script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="requirejs.config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="requirejs.js" data-main="theme"></script>
```

Also you don't need the `.js`

as per the [require.js docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main)

```
<!--when require.js loads it will inject another script tag
    (with async attribute) for scripts/main.js-->
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

Applogies... I misread the question.

I just had a quick look at the [`requirejs`](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js) source code and the reason why this works is because it is finding all `script` elements (`document.getElementsByTagName('script');`) and iterating over them to find a `data-main` attribute. So actually in theory you could define more than one script with a `data-main` and it will load all of them.

Comment: I think he knows he did it wrong. He wants to know how/why this still works anyway.

Comment: applogies, misread your question. Have updated my answer which should hopefully shed some light.